# Why is PHP trying to access my localhost database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a strange bug in my Code Igniter application. When I call mysql_real_escape_string, Code Igniter or PHP issues this error.

```
<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Warning</p>
<p>Message:  mysql_real_escape_string() [<a href='function.mysql-real-escape-string'>function.mysql-real-escape-string</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/No-MySQL-hostname-was-specified' (2)</p>
<p>Filename: helpers/formval_helper.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 13</p>
```

Why does simply calling mysql_real_escape_string trigger access to my localhost database? Doesn't that function just format a string? Also, I'm not even using my localhost database.

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_real_escape_string` in a form helper to begin with?

Comment: C'mon you have Active Record and parametrized queries available with little to no effort, why are you using that function? And why are you placing a DB method inside an helper? (ideally it should go in a model)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string() otherwise an error of level E_WARNING is generated, and FALSE is returned. If link_identifier isn't defined, the last MySQL connection is used.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `mysql_real_escape_string` is partially dependent on certain database server settings, including character set. If you want something generic, use `addslashes`, but note that it will give incorrect results for some obscure multibyte character sets.

Comment: Please do not recommend `addslashes` over `mysql_real_escape_string`. The latter is pretty bad already in this day and age, `addslashes` is even worse.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all.

Its says its not able to connect to your mysql server, with whatever credentials and servername you had provided!

You need to have a connection to your DB first, before using this function! It has some dependency on a MySql Server!

Answer (score 1):

This function has the second parameter link_identifier.
This is what documentation says:

The MySQL connection. If the link identifier is not specified, the last link opened by mysql_connect() is assumed. If no such link is found, it will try to create one as if mysql_connect() was called with no arguments. If no connection is found or established, an E_WARNING level error is generated